# exp function in dplyr mutate returning 1's

Tags: r

I am trying to convert a variable by using the exponential function however I obtain values of `1`.

```
dat %>% 
  mutate(estimate_exp = exp(estimate))
```

Which gives:

```
# A tibble: 30 x 3
# Groups:   .id [30]
   .id    estimate estimate_exp
   <chr>     <dbl>        <dbl>
 1 COP    0.000363         1.00
 2 D      0.000128         1.00
 3 MKC    0.000661         1.00
 4 XRAY  -0.000220         1.00
 5 AZO    0.000646         1.00
```

Where am I going wrong here?

Data:

```
dat <- structure(list(.id = c("COP", "D", "MKC", "XRAY", "AZO", "VZ", 
"BAX", "SIVB", "PEP", "FBHS", "AMCR", "IQV", "CHD", "AAP", "DVA", 
"EA", "AIZ", "T", "BR", "SRE", "AWK", "HON", "WRB", "LYV", "CL", 
"MAR", "AVGO", "BLK", "ES", "MMC"), estimate = c(0.000363241058456668, 
0.000128341996870166, 0.000660854807743273, -0.000220256089065116, 
0.000645752203131285, 0.000374454782366187, 0.000476331305980961, 
0.000234315048086034, 0.000267789333706011, -0.000168431145336845, 
-0.0000265813880423463, 0.000666131639082966, 0.000548256342531457, 
0.000323886569880824, -0.000118885876771656, -0.0000806822483228907, 
0.000251736455873582, -0.0000123071469196856, 0.000654303222596272, 
0.00034295710655616, 0.000529722246219021, 0.000402357094383043, 
0.000483332246532965, 0.000831519092078686, 0.00000597120397089236, 
0.000349946739694226, 0.00035884271760866, 0.000148917003006365, 
0.00041657220576363, 0.000380141826292226)), row.names = c(NA, 
-30L), groups = structure(list(.id = c("AAP", "AIZ", "AMCR", 
"AVGO", "AWK", "AZO", "BAX", "BLK", "BR", "CHD", "CL", "COP", 
"D", "DVA", "EA", "ES", "FBHS", "HON", "IQV", "LYV", "MAR", "MKC", 
"MMC", "PEP", "SIVB", "SRE", "T", "VZ", "WRB", "XRAY"), .rows = structure(list(
    14L, 17L, 11L, 27L, 21L, 5L, 7L, 28L, 19L, 13L, 25L, 1L, 
    2L, 15L, 16L, 29L, 10L, 22L, 12L, 24L, 26L, 3L, 30L, 9L, 
    8L, 20L, 18L, 6L, 23L, 4L), ptype = integer(0), class = c("vctrs_list_of", 
"vctrs_vctr"))), row.names = c(NA, -30L), .drop = FALSE, class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame")), class = c("grouped_df", "tbl_df", "tbl", 
"data.frame"))
```

Session Info:

```
R version 3.6.1 (2019-07-05)
Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)
Running under: Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS

Matrix products: default
BLAS:   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/blas/libblas.so.3.7.1
LAPACK: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/lapack/liblapack.so.3.7.1

locale:
 [1] LC_CTYPE=C.UTF-8       LC_NUMERIC=C           LC_TIME=C.UTF-8       
 [4] LC_COLLATE=C.UTF-8     LC_MONETARY=C.UTF-8    LC_MESSAGES=C.UTF-8   
 [7] LC_PAPER=C.UTF-8       LC_NAME=C              LC_ADDRESS=C          
[10] LC_TELEPHONE=C         LC_MEASUREMENT=C.UTF-8 LC_IDENTIFICATION=C   

attached base packages:
[1] grid      stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
 [1] rvest_0.3.5                xml2_1.2.2                 tibbletime_0.1.3          
 [4] tsfeatures_1.0.1           gsubfn_0.7                 proto_1.0.0               
 [7] ggmap_3.0.0                ggrepel_0.8.1              directlabels_2018.05.22   
[10] patchwork_1.0.0            cowplot_1.0.0              gtable_0.3.0              
[13] stargazer_5.2.2            e1071_1.7-3                lightgbm_2.3.2            
[16] R6_2.4.1                   tensorflow_2.0.0           keras_2.2.5.0             
[19] drlib_0.1.1                PRROC_1.3.1                pROC_1.16.1               
[22] caret_6.0-85               lattice_0.20-38            Matrix_1.2-17             
[25] xgboostExplainer_0.1       broom_0.5.3                imputeTS_3.0              
[28] data.table_1.12.8          viridis_0.5.1              viridisLite_0.3.0         
[31] CVXR_0.99-7                timetk_0.1.2               forcats_0.4.0             
[34] readr_1.3.1                tibble_2.99.99.9014        tidyverse_1.3.0           
[37] tsibble_0.8.5              rsample_0.0.5.9000         kableExtra_1.1.0          
[40] knitr_1.27                 xgboost_0.90.0.2           reticulate_1.14-9001      
[43] formatR_1.7                tidyquant_0.5.9            quantmod_0.4-15           
[46] TTR_0.23-6                 PerformanceAnalytics_1.5.3 xts_0.12-0                
[49] zoo_1.8-7                  ggplot2_3.3.0.9000         purrr_0.3.3               
[52] lubridate_1.7.4            tidyr_1.0.2                future.apply_1.4.0        
[55] furrr_0.1.0                future_1.16.0              stringr_1.4.0             
[58] stringi_1.4.5              dplyr_0.8.99.9000         

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
  [1] readxl_1.3.1           backports_1.1.5        scs_1.3-2             
  [4] selectr_0.4-2          plyr_1.8.5             splines_3.6.1         
  [7] gmp_0.5-13.6           listenv_0.8.0          tfruns_1.4            
 [10] digest_0.6.23          foreach_1.4.7          htmltools_0.4.0       
 [13] fansi_0.4.1            magrittr_1.5           recipes_0.1.9         
 [16] globals_0.12.5         modelr_0.1.5           gower_0.2.1           
 [19] R.utils_2.9.2          anytime_0.3.7          forecast_8.10         
 [22] tseries_0.10-47        jpeg_0.1-8.1           waterfalls_0.1.2      
 [25] colorspace_1.4-1       lobstr_1.1.1           haven_2.2.0           
 [28] xfun_0.12              tcltk_3.6.1            crayon_1.3.4          
 [31] jsonlite_1.6           zeallot_0.1.0          survival_2.44-1.1     
 [34] iterators_1.0.12       glue_1.3.1             ipred_0.9-9           
 [37] webshot_0.5.2          Quandl_2.10.0          ECOSolveR_0.5.3       
 [40] Rmpfr_0.8-1            scales_1.1.0           stinepack_1.4         
 [43] DBI_1.1.0              Rcpp_1.0.3             bit_1.1-15.1          
 [46] stats4_3.6.1           lava_1.6.6             prodlim_2019.11.13    
 [49] httr_1.4.1             ellipsis_0.3.0         farver_2.0.3          
 [52] pkgconfig_2.0.3        R.methodsS3_1.7.1      nnet_7.3-12           
 [55] dbplyr_1.4.2           utf8_1.1.4             labeling_0.3          
 [58] tidyselect_0.2.99.9000 rlang_0.4.4.9000       reshape2_1.4.3        
 [61] munsell_0.5.0          cellranger_1.1.0       tools_3.6.1           
 [64] cli_2.0.1              generics_0.0.2         evaluate_0.14         
 [67] ModelMetrics_1.2.2.1   bit64_0.9-7            fs_1.3.1              
 [70] RgoogleMaps_1.4.5.2    nlme_3.1-142           whisker_0.4           
 [73] R.oo_1.23.0            compiler_3.6.1         rstudioapi_0.10       
 [76] png_0.1-7              curl_4.3               testthat_2.3.1        
 [79] reprex_0.3.0           desc_1.2.0             urca_1.3-0            
 [82] vctrs_0.2.99.9005      pillar_1.4.3.9000      lifecycle_0.1.0       
 [85] lmtest_0.9-37          bitops_1.0-6           gridExtra_2.3         
 [88] codetools_0.2-16       pkgload_1.0.2          MASS_7.3-51.4         
 [91] assertthat_0.2.1       rprojroot_1.3-2        rjson_0.2.20          
 [94] withr_2.1.2            fracdiff_1.5-1         parallel_3.6.1        
 [97] hms_0.5.3              quadprog_1.5-8         rpart_4.1-15          
[100] timeDate_3043.102      class_7.3-15           rmarkdown_2.1         
[103] base64enc_0.1-3
```

EDIT:

I restarted my R Session and now I get the following output:
When I run:

```
models %>% 
  unnest(tidymodels) %>% 
  mutate(estimate_exp = exp(estimate)) %>% 
  select(estimate_exp)

# A tibble: 60 x 2
# Groups:   .id [30]
   .id   estimate_exp
   <chr>        <dbl>
 1 LEN      40.1     
 2 LEN       1.00    
 3 USB       8.47    
 4 USB       1.00    
 5 KMI       2.64    
 6 KMI       1.00    
 7 CSX       0.00592 
 8 CSX       1.00    
 9 AMT       0.000845
10 AMT       1.00
```

However when I want to filter the intercept out. I run:

```
models %>% 
  unnest(tidymodels) %>% 
  filter(term == "date") %>% 
  mutate(estimate_exp = exp(estimate)) %>% 
  select(estimate_exp)
```

Which returns:

```
# A tibble: 30 x 2
# Groups:   .id [30]
   .id   estimate_exp
   <chr>        <dbl>
 1 LEN           1.00
 2 USB           1.00
 3 KMI           1.00
 4 CSX           1.00
 5 AMT           1.00
 6 VRSK          1.00
 7 CTSH          1.00
```

EDIT: New Data:

```
d <- structure(list(date = structure(c(17445, 17410, 17707, 18108, 
17273, 17308, 17434, 18179, 17926, 18138, 18169, 17486, 17924, 
17892, 17779, 17707, 17778, 17819, 17912, 18018, 18030, 17966, 
17451, 18052, 17616, 17779, 17891, 17854, 17290, 17931, 17585, 
18047, 17732, 17360, 18191, 18002, 17260, 17616, 18040, 17954, 
17556, 17260, 17781, 17197, 17470, 17367, 18144, 17738, 18130, 
17904, 17548, 18033, 17352, 17955, 18038, 17918, 17553, 18218, 
18117, 17683, 18179, 17722, 17667, 17577, 17220, 17301, 17924, 
17883, 17513, 17263, 17170, 17848, 17392, 17445, 17696, 17183, 
17840, 18061, 17632, 17604, 17563, 18173, 17354, 17560, 17707, 
17506, 18240, 18092, 17284, 17185, 17389, 18030, 18144, 17449, 
17262, 17357, 17175, 17371, 17241, 17528, 18094, 17801, 18211, 
17836, 17213, 17802, 17347, 17409, 17388, 17961, 17662, 17430, 
17948, 18257, 17364, 17521, 17534, 17632, 17633, 17213, 17941, 
17850, 17564, 17381, 18239, 17408, 17682, 17205, 17618, 17330, 
18248, 17709, 17394, 17448, 17471, 17256, 18029, 17388, 17605, 
17606, 18236, 17721, 17766, 18246, 17646, 17645, 17584, 17443, 
17204, 18075), class = "Date"), .id = c("AES", "AES", "AES", 
"AES", "AES", "AMT", "AMT", "AMT", "AMT", "AMT", "ANET", "ANET", 
"ANET", "ANET", "ANET", "BSX", "BSX", "BSX", "BSX", "BSX", "CAH", 
"CAH", "CAH", "CAH", "CAH", "CSX", "CSX", "CSX", "CSX", "CSX", 
"CTSH", "CTSH", "CTSH", "CTSH", "CTSH", "DRE", "DRE", "DRE", 
"DRE", "DRE", "FLS", "FLS", "FLS", "FLS", "FLS", "FMC", "FMC", 
"FMC", "FMC", "FMC", "GL", "GL", "GL", "GL", "GL", "IDXX", "IDXX", 
"IDXX", "IDXX", "IDXX", "IRM", "IRM", "IRM", "IRM", "IRM", "KHC", 
"KHC", "KHC", "KHC", "KHC", "KMI", "KMI", "KMI", "KMI", "KMI", 
"LEN", "LEN", "LEN", "LEN", "LEN", "LH", "LH", "LH", "LH", "LH", 
"NI", "NI", "NI", "NI", "NI", "PG", "PG", "PG", "PG", "PG", "PKI", 
"PKI", "PKI", "PKI", "PKI", "PNR", "PNR", "PNR", "PNR", "PNR", 
"STE", "STE", "STE", "STE", "STE", "TGT", "TGT", "TGT", "TGT", 
"TGT", "TSN", "TSN", "TSN", "TSN", "TSN", "TXT", "TXT", "TXT", 
"TXT", "TXT", "USB", "USB", "USB", "USB", "USB", "V", "V", "V", 
"V", "V", "VAR", "VAR", "VAR", "VAR", "VAR", "VRSK", "VRSK", 
"VRSK", "VRSK", "VRSK", "WRB", "WRB", "WRB", "WRB", "WRB"), logPrice = c(2.31262690481122, 
2.30635169045117, 2.49697165732692, 2.80575823103745, 2.31252086928585, 
4.80346125693376, 4.87348396310791, 5.41731548591334, 5.12092195236532, 
5.43015970101662, 5.4761287594931, 5.44574551787296, 5.37212532620251, 
5.32218037657676, 5.60686770785711, 3.46947885794531, 3.58490683599171, 
3.59539261102047, 3.60059451193888, 3.60794048450097, 3.80075118572202, 
3.84870347435354, 4.10304216153996, 3.73809095807872, 4.05218391168489, 
4.2915093418645, 4.10903510912515, 4.26117499880098, 3.90724989222571, 
4.1973687457803, 4.38670773620216, 4.11642557242379, 4.38846510069663, 
4.18500121904317, 4.0863504610367, 3.37128269943617, 3.17006958256952, 
3.18009021384426, 3.40477500765288, 3.36524445148554, 3.77389751034243, 
3.8211151013729, 3.93903725264536, 3.84438609991795, 3.74785342022987, 
4.1492065728268, 4.46246432202498, 4.31288943580795, 4.4460987306459, 
4.20926604086005, 4.50684788830804, 4.46495030377449, 4.32240935765901, 
4.40604986474117, 4.47700696462918, 5.30484599857581, 5.19822073343059, 
5.56271801387212, 5.63070980997644, 5.37231105109975, 3.45598934024689, 
3.48843809068652, 3.36004231084482, 3.37536460349664, 3.40482080911292, 
4.37518653191793, 3.79395975051401, 3.77783910282242, 4.27644505291608, 
4.38906386518127, 2.95111736585753, 2.78391712539222, 2.8366591650958, 
2.8361334880473, 2.74697785849833, 3.76518525748053, 3.7879280690716, 
3.97721446335609, 4.05622744787957, 4.08519037353031, 5.15352274119173, 
5.11889157697021, 5.02025551766473, 5.1824013425652, 5.23383215065638, 
3.22833126100395, 3.28876491862797, 3.36052072380224, 3.10764723681244, 
3.01049166587651, 4.43882718935099, 4.64091289635708, 4.7979409838123, 
4.44188794171029, 4.40192526226385, 4.21688739280126, 3.96749580052182, 
4.23110131236768, 4.01569559534048, 4.28884091285977, 3.61520549161055, 
3.74522408275384, 3.76012095221071, 3.69438149011566, 3.60258850846041, 
4.72667073866304, 4.37116125716819, 4.44195754534013, 4.40896534484866, 
4.78073885158278, 4.1903947560273, 3.98590899008732, 4.24887435589091, 
4.85576407363082, 3.89256022837633, 4.3526464453551, 4.33461888702626, 
4.21898405338856, 4.21089132289427, 4.11246263419644, 3.98734563102018, 
4.04207282440258, 4.07526104130694, 3.88859502085857, 3.79300948803953, 
3.87556692475429, 3.86121658197339, 3.88966687912656, 3.8628154921807, 
3.89593807372985, 5.21836789911083, 4.86421073302128, 4.62157623772135, 
4.65666772951537, 4.69390605684972, 4.51228702558803, 4.86321746876136, 
4.57109622634756, 4.83134910191856, 4.82703288536157, 4.98750307545778, 
4.70767708896336, 4.75852663335337, 5.00856650228809, 4.66229597874042, 
3.88036423339266, 3.79985582131739, 3.77971436208379, 3.77679041802056, 
4.18548608036901)), groups = structure(list(.id = c("AES", "AMT", 
"ANET", "BSX", "CAH", "CSX", "CTSH", "DRE", "FLS", "FMC", "GL", 
"IDXX", "IRM", "KHC", "KMI", "LEN", "LH", "NI", "PG", "PKI", 
"PNR", "STE", "TGT", "TSN", "TXT", "USB", "V", "VAR", "VRSK", 
"WRB"), .rows = structure(list(1:5, 6:10, 11:15, 16:20, 21:25, 
    26:30, 31:35, 36:40, 41:45, 46:50, 51:55, 56:60, 61:65, 66:70, 
    71:75, 76:80, 81:85, 86:90, 91:95, 96:100, 101:105, 106:110, 
    111:115, 116:120, 121:125, 126:130, 131:135, 136:140, 141:145, 
    146:150), ptype = integer(0), class = c("vctrs_list_of", 
"vctrs_vctr"))), row.names = c(NA, -30L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"), .drop = TRUE), row.names = c(NA, -150L), class = c("grouped_df", 
"tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Now I run:

```
    models2 <- d %>% 
  group_by(.id) %>% 
  nest() %>% 
  mutate(models = map(data, ~lm(logPrice ~ date, data = .x))) %>% 
  mutate(
    tidymodels = map(models, ~tidy(.x)),
    glancemodels = map(models, ~glance(.x)),
    augmentmodels = map(models, ~augment(.x))
  )
```

Then I run:

```
models2 %>% 
  unnest(tidymodels) %>% 
  filter(term == "date") %>% 
  mutate(estimate_exp = exp(estimate)) %>% 
  select(estimate_exp)
```

Which gives me the output:

```
Adding missing grouping variables: `.id`
# A tibble: 30 x 2
# Groups:   .id [30]
   .id   estimate_exp
   <chr>        <dbl>
 1 AES          1.00 
 2 AMT          1.00 
 3 ANET         1.00 
 4 BSX          1.00 
 5 CAH          0.999
 6 CSX          1.00
```

So its a rounding problem I guess.

EDIT:

Taking the data `d`:

I get the following output:

```
> models2 <- d %>% 
+   group_by(.id) %>% 
+   nest() %>% 
+   mutate(models = map(data, ~lm(logPrice ~ date, data = .x))) %>% 
+   mutate(
+     tidymodels = map(models, ~tidy(.x)),
+     glancemodels = map(models, ~glance(.x)),
+     augmentmodels = map(models, ~augment(.x))
+   )
> 
> modl1 <- models2 %>% 
+   unnest(tidymodels) %>% 
+   filter(term == "date")
> 
> exp(modl1$estimate)
 [1] 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
>
```

EDIT: with a refresh R session I run the following:

```
library(dplyr)
library(broom)
library(purrr)


models2 <- d %>% 
  group_by(.id) %>% 
  nest() %>% 
  mutate(models = map(data, ~lm(logPrice ~ date, data = .x))) %>% 
  mutate(
    tidymodels = map(models, ~tidy(.x)),
    glancemodels = map(models, ~glance(.x)),
    augmentmodels = map(models, ~augment(.x))
  )


mod1 <- models2 %>% unnest(tidymodels) %>% filter(term == "date")
exp(mod1$estimate)
```

Which gives:

```
 [1] 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
```

Session Info:

```
R version 3.6.1 (2019-07-05)
Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)
Running under: Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS

Matrix products: default
BLAS:   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/blas/libblas.so.3.7.1
LAPACK: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/lapack/liblapack.so.3.7.1

locale:
 [1] LC_CTYPE=C.UTF-8       LC_NUMERIC=C           LC_TIME=C.UTF-8       
 [4] LC_COLLATE=C.UTF-8     LC_MONETARY=C.UTF-8    LC_MESSAGES=C.UTF-8   
 [7] LC_PAPER=C.UTF-8       LC_NAME=C              LC_ADDRESS=C          
[10] LC_TELEPHONE=C         LC_MEASUREMENT=C.UTF-8 LC_IDENTIFICATION=C   

attached base packages:
[1] grid      stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
 [1] gsubfn_0.7                 proto_1.0.0                ggmap_3.0.0               
 [4] ggrepel_0.8.1              directlabels_2018.05.22    patchwork_1.0.0           
 [7] cowplot_1.0.0              gtable_0.3.0               stargazer_5.2.2           
[10] e1071_1.7-3                lightgbm_2.3.2             R6_2.4.1                  
[13] tensorflow_2.0.0           keras_2.2.5.0              drlib_0.1.1               
[16] PRROC_1.3.1                pROC_1.16.1                caret_6.0-85              
[19] lattice_0.20-38            Matrix_1.2-17              xgboostExplainer_0.1      
[22] broom_0.5.3                imputeTS_3.0               data.table_1.12.8         
[25] viridis_0.5.1              viridisLite_0.3.0          CVXR_0.99-7               
[28] timetk_0.1.2               forcats_0.4.0              readr_1.3.1               
[31] tibble_2.99.99.9014        tidyverse_1.3.0            tsibble_0.8.5             
[34] rsample_0.0.5.9000         kableExtra_1.1.0           knitr_1.27                
[37] xgboost_0.90.0.2           reticulate_1.14-9001       formatR_1.7               
[40] tidyquant_0.5.9            quantmod_0.4-15            TTR_0.23-6                
[43] PerformanceAnalytics_1.5.3 xts_0.12-0                 zoo_1.8-7                 
[46] ggplot2_3.3.0.9000         purrr_0.3.3                lubridate_1.7.4           
[49] tidyr_1.0.2                future.apply_1.4.0         furrr_0.1.0               
[52] future_1.16.0              stringr_1.4.0              stringi_1.4.5             
[55] dplyr_0.8.99.9000         

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] readxl_1.3.1           backports_1.1.5        scs_1.3-2             
 [4] plyr_1.8.5             splines_3.6.1          gmp_0.5-13.6          
 [7] listenv_0.8.0          tfruns_1.4             digest_0.6.23         
[10] foreach_1.4.7          htmltools_0.4.0        fansi_0.4.1           
[13] magrittr_1.5           recipes_0.1.9          globals_0.12.5        
[16] modelr_0.1.5           gower_0.2.1            R.utils_2.9.2         
[19] anytime_0.3.7          forecast_8.10          tseries_0.10-47       
[22] jpeg_0.1-8.1           waterfalls_0.1.2       colorspace_1.4-1      
[25] rvest_0.3.5            lobstr_1.1.1           haven_2.2.0           
[28] xfun_0.12              tcltk_3.6.1            crayon_1.3.4          
[31] jsonlite_1.6           zeallot_0.1.0          survival_2.44-1.1     
[34] iterators_1.0.12       glue_1.3.1             ipred_0.9-9           
[37] webshot_0.5.2          Quandl_2.10.0          ECOSolveR_0.5.3       
[40] Rmpfr_0.8-1            scales_1.1.0           stinepack_1.4         
[43] DBI_1.1.0              Rcpp_1.0.3             bit_1.1-15.1          
[46] stats4_3.6.1           lava_1.6.6             prodlim_2019.11.13    
[49] httr_1.4.1             ellipsis_0.3.0         pkgconfig_2.0.3       
[52] R.methodsS3_1.7.1      nnet_7.3-12            dbplyr_1.4.2          
[55] utf8_1.1.4             tidyselect_0.2.99.9000 rlang_0.4.4.9000      
[58] reshape2_1.4.3         munsell_0.5.0          cellranger_1.1.0      
[61] tools_3.6.1            cli_2.0.1              generics_0.0.2        
[64] evaluate_0.14          ModelMetrics_1.2.2.1   bit64_0.9-7           
[67] fs_1.3.1               RgoogleMaps_1.4.5.2    nlme_3.1-142          
[70] whisker_0.4            R.oo_1.23.0            xml2_1.2.2            
[73] compiler_3.6.1         rstudioapi_0.10        png_0.1-7             
[76] curl_4.3               reprex_0.3.0           urca_1.3-0            
[79] vctrs_0.2.99.9005      pillar_1.4.3.9000      lifecycle_0.1.0       
[82] lmtest_0.9-37          bitops_1.0-6           gridExtra_2.3         
[85] codetools_0.2-16       MASS_7.3-51.4          assertthat_0.2.1      
[88] rjson_0.2.20           withr_2.1.2            fracdiff_1.5-1        
[91] parallel_3.6.1         hms_0.5.3              quadprog_1.5-8        
[94] rpart_4.1-15           timeDate_3043.102      class_7.3-15          
[97] rmarkdown_2.1          base64enc_0.1-3
```

Comment: I also have the same package version `packageVersion('dplyr')#
[1] ‘0.8.99.9000’` on `R 3.6.2`

Comment: Can you check the output of `exp(dat$estimate)` i.e. we are directly extracting the column and  get the `exp`

Comment: The error occurs when I apply the `filter` - I added an EDIT.

Comment: Because you have loaded lots of packages, is there a chance that `mutate` or `exp` got masked by same function from another package

Comment: Try `dplyr::filter(term == "date")` in case the function got masked

Comment: What is the output of `exp(dat$estimate)` after the `filter`

Comment: I added another edit. Running the following `mod1 <- models %>% 
  unnest(tidymodels) %>% 
  filter(term == "date") 
  

exp(mod1$estimate)` gives, `1 1 1 1 1...`

Comment: I am able to reproduce the print format, but not when I extract the values

Comment: I just applied your new update and still obtain `1 1 1 1 1...`. Is it just a tidyverse rounding issue?

Comment: it could be a rounding issue but the `exp(mod1$estimate)` should give the full output as I can't reproduce

Comment: I added an additional edit with the output.

Comment: For me, it is giving `exp(modl1$estimate)#
 [1] 1.0006405 1.0007140 0.9999498 1.0003551 0.9994210 1.0004718 0.9997622 1.0003188 1.0001203 1.0003742
[11] 1.0001127 1.0005580 1.0000700 0.9990263 0.9997404 1.0001405 1.0000650 1.0002640 1.0004100 1.0009941
[21] 1.0000995 1.0006812 1.0009634 1.0002974 0.9998595 0.9999282 1.0006958 1.0004811 1.0005498 1.0004972`

Comment: I would check  with only dplyr and broom loaded on a fresh R session

Comment: will check now.

Comment: also with `purrr` i guess

Comment: I added another edit. With a fresh R session.

Comment: I installed the dev version of dplyr only couple of days back.  Can you reinstall it again or test it on a R 3.6.2 as I can't reproduce.  My testing was done on `Mac`

Comment: I have to leave now.  Will check later

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is nothing wrong.  If we extract the values in the column, it would give the full value instead of the `print` formatted tbl_df column value

```
library(dplyr)
dat %>% 
   mutate(estimate_exp = exp(estimate)) %>%
   pull(estimate_exp)
#[1] 1.0003633 1.0001284 1.0006611 0.9997798 1.0006460 1.0003745 1.0004764 1.0002343 1.0002678 0.9998316
#[11] 0.9999734 1.0006664 1.0005484 1.0003239 0.9998811 0.9999193 1.0002518 0.9999877 1.0006545 1.0003430
#[21] 1.0005299 1.0004024 1.0004834 1.0008319 1.0000060 1.0003500 1.0003589 1.0001489 1.0004167 1.0003802
```

Also, we don't need the group_by attribute

```
dat %>%
    ungroup %>%
    mutate(estimate_exp = exp(estimate)) %>% 
    pull(estimate_exp)
#[1] 1.0003633 1.0001284 1.0006611 0.9997798 1.0006460 1.0003745 1.0004764 1.0002343 1.0002678 0.9998316
#[11] 0.9999734 1.0006664 1.0005484 1.0003239 0.9998811 0.9999193 1.0002518 0.9999877 1.0006545 1.0003430
#[21] 1.0005299 1.0004024 1.0004834 1.0008319 1.0000060 1.0003500 1.0003589 1.0001489 1.0004167 1.0003802
```

#### Update

With the new data 'd'

```
models2 %>% 
   unnest(tidymodels) %>%
   ungroup %>%
   filter(term == "date") %>% 
   mutate(estimate_exp = exp(estimate)) %>% 
   select(estimate_exp) %>% pull(estimate_exp)
#[1] 1.0006405 1.0007140 0.9999498 1.0003551 0.9994210 1.0004718 0.9997622 1.0003188 1.0001203 1.0003742
#[11] 1.0001127 1.0005580 1.0000700 0.9990263 0.9997404 1.0001405 1.0000650 1.0002640 1.0004100 1.0009941
#[21] 1.0000995 1.0006812 1.0009634 1.0002974 0.9998595 0.9999282 1.0006958 1.0004811 1.0005498 1.0004972
```

Comment: ohh I see! this makes sense. How can I make my output have more decimal places? When I apply your code I get: `1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1` I have `options(scipen=999)`

Comment: @user113156 is it because of a package version difference as I can't reproduce that

Comment: @user113156  there is a grup_by attribute, which you can remove as well `dat %>% ungroup %>% mutate(estimate_exp = exp(estimate)) %>% pull(estimate_exp)`

Comment: Using `dat %>%
  ungroup(.id) %>%
  mutate(estimate_exp = exp(estimate)) %>% 
  pull(estimate_exp)` still gives me the `1 1 1 1 1...` output.

Comment: @user113156 i use the devel version of `dplyr`

Comment: I added my session info.

Comment: I went back to this problem. The problem occurs since `tibble`s round the data. Adding `as.data.frame()` between the `select` and `pull` such as `select(estimate_exp) %>% 
  as.data.frame() %>% 
  pull(estimate_exp)` gives me the full non-rounded output.

Comment: @user113156 maybe it is `tibble` version.  I used `packageVersion('tibble')#
[1] ‘2.99.99.9014’` i.e. the devel version when I installed the dplyr devel

Comment: Okay, looks like that is also the same.  Sorry no idea why it behaved like it

Comment: I am also using this version. Perhaps it is something to do with `dplyr`, I don't know. but adding the `data.frame` solves me issue. Thanks again!